# What if thread exit before other thread wait for it(join)?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, pthreads, pthread-join

For example, If I create 3 threads and join them in the same order. If the second thread exit first, then what would happen to the pthread_join. Will the program block until tid1 exits or directly return from pthread_join(&tid2,NULL)?

```
   pthread_t tid1,tid2,tid3;
   pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, SomeFun, NULL);
   pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, SomeFun, NULL);
   pthread_create(&tid3, NULL, SomeFun, NULL);
   pthread_join(&tid1, NULL);
   pthread_join(&tid2, NULL);
   pthread_join(&tid3, NULL);
```

Comment: `pthread_join()` is not the dreaded "come from".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you code calls:

```
pthread_join(&tid1, NULL);
```

if `tid1` has not exited yet, then that call will block until it does.  if `tid2` exits in the meantime, that doesn't change the behavior of this particular call.  But in that scenario, when the call does return, the next call:

```
pthread_join(&tid2, NULL);
```

will return immediately since the `tid2` has already exited.

If you want to immediately perform some work when an arbitrary thread is finished, you'll need to use something other than `pthread_join()` to synchronize with the "some thread is finished" event.  Perhaps waiting on a condition variable that gets signaled by every thread when they complete (along with some mechanism such as a queue so the waiting thread can determine which thread has signaled completion).  Another mechanism that could be used is to have threads write information to a pipe that the main (or controlling) thread reads to get that notification.

Answer (score 1):

If you join a thread that has already ended, `pthread_join` will return immediately (and destroy the thread object, like it normally does).

Comment: So it will execute pthread_join(&tid1,NULL) first and then immediately return from pthread_join(&tid2,NULL) and go on to wait for tid3?